# Failed to recognize HDMI cable and purple screen Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, hdmi, amd-graphics

I am using notebook with the following specifications:

- Intel i7-8550U
- AMD radeon R7
- Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot windows)

When I plug a hdmi cable nothing happens.

I actually found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978663/xrandr-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-for-mdp-type-connection) changing the `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = quiet splash"` to `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1"` in the /etc/default/grub file.

But the thing is, sometimes I turn on my computer, insert my password, the system goes back to the password screen, I retype my password and it stucks at a purple screen after the second log in. So I found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074846/ubuntu-18-stuck-at-purple-screen-after-log-in-how-to-fix-this/1074856) (again) to this problem that involves changing the same line of the previously problem in the /etc/default/grub file to `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = quiet splash nomodeset"`.

So, whenever it stucks at the purple screen. I turn off the computer, boot with the kernel in recovery mode, change the grub file as in the second solution, run `sudo update-grub`, turn off the computer, turn on computer with normal boot, change the grub file as in the first solution, run `sudo update-grub` and my two problems are solved. But sometimes I get the purple screen again. What do I do? I can send any specifications or outputs required to help identify the problem.

Ps.: I don't know if (and don't have technical knowledge) it's somewhat related but I noticed that that happens when I turn the computer with the mouse wireless USB inserted. Does that have anything related to the problem?